# Gradle Wrapper incompatible version with project

Tags: gradle

Can You help solve this problem?

on the site:
https://guides.gradle.org/executing-gradle-builds-on-teamcity

Downloaded the test project: software

https://github.com/gradle/gradle-site-plugin.git

Cradle is installed in version 3.2 to be compatible with the project. 
If I install Gradle of a newer version, then the build error in the logs: incompatible Gradle:

```
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.gradle.build-scan', version: '3.2']
The buildscan plugin is not compatible with this version of Gradle.
```

I run the build from the command line like this:

```
./ gradle build
```

Git Bash logs:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
```

My Gradle Daemon version: 5.4.1
After the build, an error with an incompatible version appears again:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
```

but Gradle still 3.2 wher I type:

```
gradle -v
```

in CMD.

In this project:
gradle-site-plugin\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip
```

Can be without updates version of build as something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you don't understand difference between gradle et gradlew (wrapper).

in your project if you use gradle wrapper, no need to install gradle program on your  computer. You can run gradle task  by typing `./gradlew yourTaskName`.

So gradle version and gradlew can be different.

`gradle -v`  will display the version of your manualy installed gradle in your computer.

`gradlew -v`  will display the version of  gradle wrapped in your project. As  it seems you are using gradle wrapper, this version is definitely the one that matters to you.

to build your project you should probably run `./gradlew build`

Comment: thank you very much for the information. Now I run the gradle wrapper project using the `gradlew build` command.
Such a strange thing, wrapper v 5. 4.1 in project, but during the build in the log writes an error:
_Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0._
Something launches Gradle v 6.0